# Stop/Cancel a request if the last request is still running

Tags: python, flask, request, flask-restful

I created a flask app that handles a optimization that takes pretty long.
I want to stop/cancel a request (and give back an error message and maybe return `False`) if the last request for this Resource is still running.
How can I do this?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

optimization_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
optimization_args.add_argument("run", type=str, help="Long or short run", required=True, choices=("long", "short", "test"), default="short")

class Optimization(Resource):
    def post(self):
       ....
       return response

api.add_resource(Optimization, "/optimization")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host= '0.0.0.0', port='5002', threaded=False)
```

```
response = requests.post(BASE + "optimization", {"run":"test"})
print(response.json())
```

Comment: How long is "pretty long"?

Comment: Anywhere from 10 minutes to 8 hours. Depending if I want a "short" or a "long" run.

Comment: The "right" way to do it is to process your optimization in a separate thread. Then you can simply check to see if that process already exists whenever a user makes their request. This is usually done with a package like [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html).